# What do we do with questions that have a duplicate on another SE site?

Tags: discussion

I'm specifically referring to [Is obtrusive JavaScript required to support a feature of AngularJS?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/269596/is-obtrusive-javascript-required-to-support-a-feature-of-angular-js), in which a decent conceptual question about "obtrusive" Javascript was asked, only for the OP himself to discover an answer already on Stack Overflow.

Since we can't close it as a duplicate of an SO question, what should we do with it? Ideally I'd like a solution that doesn't involve that user losing reputation, since I don't think he did anything particularly wrong, but the question probably shouldn't be left open either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually vote to close with a custom close reason of "duplicate on (site)" & provide a link.  As you noted, it's not a formal duplicate, but it's as close as we can get.

Comment: Duh, a custom close reason. I forgot those existed since I don't have the rep to do any close voting at all.